# This jquery selector not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I want to attach an onclick event to `a`, but cannot seem to achieve it with this:

```
$("[class^=field-promote_image_]").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find('.file-upload > a');
    a.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(a.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

nor with this:

```
$("[class^=field-promote_image_] .file-upload > a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Is anchor element added dynamically? Add live demo

Comment: because the class attribute has `form-row` at the beginning so attribute starts with selector won't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
$('.field-row[class*="field-promote_image_"] .file-upload > a').on('click', , function() {
```

**Warning:** This will match all the elements whose class contains `field-promote_image_`. Ex. `anything-field-promote_image_`

Comment: Would match `anything-field-promote_image_` too

Comment: I want to catch click event on anchor child of `class*="field-promote_image_`

Comment: @doniyor Please read the warning at the bottom, it has side-effects

Comment: don't use event delegation in this case if it is not necessary as the attribute selector could be very costly

Comment: @ArunPJohny As OP is adding the elements dynamically in the DOM, event delegation has to be used.

Comment: I dont need delegation since the elements are not added dynamically. but the regexp was the bit and the side effect wont happen in my case. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I assume the class `field-promote_image_de` is dynamic that is why you are going for the attribute starts with selector, but it won't work because that is not the starting of the attribute value.

A right approach here will be is to add an additional class to that element like

```
<div class="form-row field-promote_image field-promote_image_de">
   ...
</div>
```

then just use the new class

```
$('.field-promote_image a').click(function(){
    //your handler code
})
```

Comment: thanks Arun! but I cannot add custom class, since the whole form is added dynamically

Comment: nice, the second solutions is it

Comment: @doniyor see Tushar's answer below... it is very generic but could fit your problem if you can work with the restrictions

Comment: ah damn, any ideas without custom class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(".file-upload > a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: this is too generic and apply to those a's that I dont want